# Count all files in a directory using datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm almost there with a script to count the files in the last 18 hours in a specific directory. We expect 12 a day, so it's good for the person running the script to see how many files are there, and can investigate based on this script.

My current script is as follow:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME= GetDate() --Get now
DECLARE @TimeD INT = -18 --Number of hours to look into the past

create table #regop(
[date] dateTime,
depth int,
[file] int)

insert into #regop

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_dirtree N'\\location...\', 1, 1

select count([file]) from #regop
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, LEFT([date],8), 1) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
and [file]=1 and [date] >= DATEADD(HH,@TimeD,@Now)

drop table #regop
```

I'm currently getting

`Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_dirtree, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]`

`Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.`

Can anyone assist where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are going wrong by doing this in SQL. File access should be done using external scripts, such as Powershell, batch cmd, or C#. The `xp_` procedures are undocumented, subject to removal at any time, and have security issues. Your filename clearly doesn't fit a `datetime` column which is where you are trying to insert

Comment: what format datetime is in file name?

Comment: For example in PS you can try this `Get-ChildItem -File | where { $dat=[datetime]::MinValue; [datetime]::TryParse($_.Name.SubString(0, 8), [ref] $dat) -eq (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(18)  }`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think it is not possible to retrieve data when the file was created with xp_dirtree. As an first output argument that function returns file name which is nvarchar, not an data. That part cause an error. You can fix that by changing data type in temporary table:

```
create table #regop(
--[date] dateTime,
[file_name] nvarchar(512),
depth int,
[file] int)
```